# What is the most efficient way to convert long to HH:mm:ss and display it in a label?

Tags: java, swing, time, format, jlabel

I'm wanting to have my JLabel display values in the format of `HH:mm:ss` without making use of any external libraries. (the label will update every second)

So for example, the following input in seconds and the desired output are below:

```
Seconds:                             Output: 
--------------------------------------------------
long seconds = 0                    00:00:00
long seconds = 5                    00:00:05
long seconds = 500                  00:08:20
long seconds = 5000                 01:23:20

Note: the seconds value is of type long
```

I'm aware that typically one would just do the following conversions to get the desired numbers:

```
long s = 5000;              //total seconds 

long hrs = (s / 3600)       //hours
long mins = ((s%3600)/60)   //minutes
long secs = (s%60)          //seconds
```

However, this leaves decimals on the values. Perhaps there is some sort of formatting that will allow me to toss the un-needed decimals.

Options I have come across were `String.format()`, `SimpleDateFormat()`, or concatenating a string myself.

The thing is, I will be updating this JLabel every second and sometimes it can count to the equivalent of 5-6 days if not longer.

So I'm looking for someone who has more experience in the area than I, and knows the most efficient way to tackle this issue.

Comment: Re: "sometimes it can count to the equivalent of 5-6 days": in that case, would it wrap around back to `00:00:00`, or would you want to display the number of days somehow?

Comment: Re: "However, this leaves decimals on the values": I don't know what you mean. In Java, if `s` is a `long`, then `s / 3600` is a long; it performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), so no decimal point is produced.

Comment: @ruakh I may have to add a days category in the, but I haven't encountered it yet. I just know that I will encounter it in the future. For now I just wanted to make sure that I could at least make hours, minutes, and seconds display appropriately. Also as for the long, I briefly tested it in Groovy rather than Java, perhaps it converted the types without me knowing which is why it showed decimals. (which I wasn't aware of until you pointed it out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a formatter class, you can get your work done by using basic operations like conversion among wrapper classes and String operations. Take a look at this code:

```
long h, m, s; // Initialize them after calculation.
String h1, m1, s1;

h1 = Long.toString( h );
m1 = Long.toString( m );
s1 = Long.toString( s );

if ( s1.length() < 2 )
    s1 = "0" + s1;
if ( m1.length() < 2 )
    m1 = "0" + m1;
if ( h1.length() < 2 )
    h1 = "0" + h1;

String output = h1+":"+m1+":"+s1;
```

Supposing you have **correctly calculated values of seconds, minutes and hours**, you can gather String versions of these variables, then format them with a simple length check and finally concatenate these time unit parts.

Comment: I like this method as well. It even works with values larger than 24 hours (for when I need to deal with it).

Comment: @StartingGroovy Once upon a time i used this method for a game implementation, and i was updating a label with timer value just like you are trying to do now. check this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mybullsandcows

Comment: I've decided to go with your string concatenation for the time being as it seems to do a pretty good job for my task at hand :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I would use SimpleDateFormat if I were you.

If SDF is too slow for you, profile all your options and pick the fastest one, then refactor the rest of your code until it's fast enough.

Remember that ***premature optimization is the root of all evil***, and that you should only really do any optimizing *after* you've profiled your code *and* missed your target execution time.

Comment: @Chris Browne I like the advice given about Optimization as well. I'm testing each solution provided and seeing how they go.

Answer (score 3):

SimpleDateFormat() is really quite appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Centinski I figured that SimpleDateFormat would have been the preferred way. Thanks for the response. I'm going to test it as well as the others.

Comment: Thanks for giving your input, +1 for the answer and your time :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class, as shown [here](http://mre-anotherprogrammersblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/java-how-to-format-milliseconds-to.html) in combination with the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class set to execute at 1 second intervals.

Comment: I like the example and gave it a try. The example linked to may have a syntax error due to an extra closed parenthesis. Aside from that, will all this conversion be as efficient as SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: I wanted to thank you for showing me `TimeUnit`. While I didn't chose this option, I'm glad you revealed another way of doing it! Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind values wrapping then use SimpleDateFormat as follows. Remember x1000 to convert to milliseconds and to manually override the timezone.

```
long value = 5 * 24 * 3600 + 5000;

// wrapping solution
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
// ensure no daylight saving +1 hour
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(value * 1000));
```

Output

```
01:23:20
```

If you want the hours to go past 23.59.59 then this is the simplest I could come up with. I used DecimalFormat to force at least 2 digits for the hours.

```
long value = 5 * 24 * 3600 + 5000;

long hours = value / 3600; // whole hours
long mins = value / 60 - hours * 60;
long secs = value % 60;
System.out.println(String.format("%s:%2d:%2d",
        new DecimalFormat("00").format(hours), mins, secs));
```

Output

```
121:23:20
```

Comment: I'm glad you added in the second example and provided what the output would look like as eventually I'm sure the time will exceed 24 hours

Comment: I just wanted to thank you as well. I appreciate when a user offers source as an example. It's a great way to test methods against each other. Thank you for your time Adam

Answer (score 2):

I've found this to be extremely fast. Try it out. Seconds go from 0 - 59, minutes go from 0 - 59, hours go from 0 - 2,562,047,788,015. Afterwards the hours become negative and begin going towards that maximum.

performing the "+" operator on Strings is very slow. A StringBuilder performs grouping strings together the fastest from what I've seen. You should also be using "chars" not "String/Byte" Bytes are very slow as well. I'd prefer doing only multiplication however dividing by 36 and 6 give decimals that are to large for holding.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);
    long hours = time / 3600000;
    long minutes = (time - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
    long seconds = (time - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;

    if (hours < 10)
        sb.append('0');
    sb.append(hours);
    sb.append(':');

    if (minutes < 10)
        sb.append('0');
    sb.append(minutes);
    sb.append(':');

    if (seconds < 10)
        sb.append('0');
    sb.append(seconds);

    String formattedTime = sb.toString();
```

.....

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to do the math you indicated, but take the floor of each value. then concatenate..

```
public class Test{ 
   public static void main(String args[]){
      double d = -100.675;
      float f = -90;    

      System.out.println(Math.floor(d));
      System.out.println(Math.floor(f)); 

      System.out.println(Math.ceil(d));
      System.out.println(Math.ceil(f));
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that's really bad advice. Integer division of positive values computes the floor with absolutely no risk of round-off error; that can't be said of your approach.